# Why is $\sin(x^3)$ odd?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

So I know this is probably a really obvious question, but I'm a bit unclear on this. Why is $\sin(x^3)$ odd?

Is it because you can substitute $u = x^3$ and then $\sin(x^3)=\sin(u)$

Then you can say  $\sin(-u) = -\sin(u)$?

The part about this that seems weird to me is that I don't understand why rules for $\sin(x)$ should work for $\sin(f(x))$. If someone can please explain to me what is going on that would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: This is *not* true for general functions of the form $\sin f(x)$---consider the similar case $f(x) = x^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure definition:

A function $f$ is odd if $f(-x) = - f(x)$ for all $x$.

So $\sin((-x)^3) = \sin(-x^3) = - \sin (x^3)$.

So it is odd.

.......

One thing to note, is that if $f$ is odd, and $g$ is also odd then $f\circ g$ is odd because:

$f(g(-x) = f(-g(x)) = -f(g(x))$.

And $x^3$ is odd because $(-x)^3 = (-1*x)^3 = (-1)^3x^3 = (-1)*x^3 = -x^3$

An $\sin x$ is odd because .... well, it's a basic trigonometric identity that $\sin (-x) = -\sin (x)$.  Just draw a picture.  The $y$ value of a point of a circle at an angle will be the negative of the  $y$ value of the angle in the opposite direction.

=====

> Is it because you can substitute $u=x^3$ and then $sin(x^3)=sin(u)$ Then you can say $sin(−u)=−sin(u)$?

Only if you can *also* say that $-u = (-x)^3$.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes looking at a general case is useful.

A composition of odd functions $f$ and $g$ will be odd, since $$f \circ g (-x)=f(g(-x))=f(-g(x))=-f(g(x))=-f\circ g(x).$$

In your case, writing $\sin(x^3)$ as the composition $f \circ g$ of $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $g(x)=x^3$ shows that $\sin(x^3)$ is odd.

However, if you were to compose two functions, one odd and one even (let $f$ be odd and $g$ even),

$$f\circ g(-x)=f(g(-x))=f(g(x))=f\circ g(x)$$
$$g \circ f (-x)=g(f(-x))=g(-f(x))=g(f(x))=g \circ f(x) $$

you'd get an even function.

Answer (score 2):

Both $\sin$ and $x\mapsto x^3$ are odd functions -- and it is easy to show that the composition of two odd functions is odd:
$$ (f\circ g)(-x) = f(g(-x)) = f(-g(x)) = -f(g(x)) = -(f\circ g)(x) $$

Answer (score 1):

Because $$\sin((-x)^3)=\sin(-x^3)=-\sin{x^3}$$

Comment: I find your answer hard to read because of the lack of parenthesis... it is unclear what is affected by the minus sign and what is to the power of $3$

Comment: For $(\sin{x})^3$ there is $\sin^3x$.I think it's clear if you want to understand. -2 for you.

Comment: I've got to admit that when I see $\sin(z)^3$ I interpret it as $(\sin z)^3$ and not as $\sin(z^3)$.  And for a OP at this level, I think it would be unclear.

Comment: @fleablood me too. I notate it this way: $f(x)^2 = \big(f(x)\big)^2$, $f^2(x) = f\big(f(x)\big)$ and $f(x^2)$ is just simply as is. If I have $f^2(x)^2$ then this is $\left\{f\big(f(x)\big)\right\}^2$. In this case, I use $\{\ldots\}$ as a third last bracket after two normal brackets $(\ldots)$, which is similar to Ramanujan's notation.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$(-x)^3=-x^3$$ and $$\sin(-x^3)=-\sin(x^3)$$

Answer (score 1):

In more generality (which you suggest you want): if $f$ is odd then
$$
f(-x) = -f(x).
$$
When you use that fact inside $\sin(f(x)$ then the fact that $\sin$ is odd tells you the composition is odd.

What could you say about the composition if $f$ were even?